# Validations issue on deleting events of a jQuery Full Calendar

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax, fullcalendar

If Event is not deleted, I want to display an alert message "Event Can't be deleted"

I have done Delete operation on my table(events) and it works fine, and data is fetching from a view(events_view), If I delete any event coming from view, then I have to show "Event can't be Deleted", but it shows me the "Event Removed"...

delete.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))     
{

  $sql = "DELETE FROM events where id=? ";

  $params = array($_POST['id']); 

  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$params);

  $rows_affected = sqlsrv_rows_affected( $stmt );  

  if ($rows_affected == 0 || $rows_affected == -1 )
  {

    echo "<script> alert('Event cannot be deleted');</script>";
   }
}
```

calendarview.php:

```
eventClick:function(event)
        {
          if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?"))
          {
            var id = parseInt(event.id);
            /////////////alert(id); //////////////////
            $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo site_url('Calendar/delete');?>",
              type:"POST",
              data:{id:id},
              success:function(data)
              {
                calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                alert("Event Removed");
              }
            })
          }
        },
```

If Event deleted,Simply I want to show the message "Event Removed",
else I have to show "Event can't be removed"

Comment: So what's the problem? You are getting any errors?

Comment: It's never going to show `"Event can't be Deleted"` because that's contained in the `data` variable in your `success` callback, which you're currently doing nothing with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But I want to show success message, if it is success only... Otherwise I have to show Failure message... Please give me some suggestion, because I am new to Javascript....

Comment: You can set the HTTP response code to an error (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) then add an `error: function() { ... }` to your AJAX options, or you could output your own JSON response, e.g. `{"success": false}` then parse that in your "success" callback.

Comment: Change `echo "<script> alert('Event cannot be deleted');</script>";` to simply `echo "Event cannot be deleted";` and change `alert("Event Removed");` to `alert(data);`. That way 1) you aren't trying to output code from php - you should output only data, because you can write any code you like in the JavaScript already, and 2) you are including the data sent from the server in your alert, instead of a fixed message

Comment: Hi I done as you suggested, but it does not giving me any alert message in both scenarios(Event Deleted and Not Deleted)